# Laravel + Bootstrap Icons

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-8, bootstrap-icons

I added bootstrap-icons to my Laravel 8 project via command line `npm i bootstrap-icons`

I had already run before `npm install` and `npm run dev` to enable Laravel/UI.

But when I try to insert a simple icon `<i class = "bi bi-alarm"> </i>`,  it is not displayed.

Comment: if you want to use bootstrap or bootstrap-icons with Vite in Laravel then follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139847/14344959

Answer (score 5):

Edit file: *resources/sass/app.scss* and add:

```
// Bootstrap-icons
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```

Then rebuild:

```
$ npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Laravel 10

Install bootstrap icons with:

```
sail npm i bootstrap-icons
```

Then update you're vite-config and add the resolve part:

```
plugins: [
    ...
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap-icons': path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules/bootstrap-icons'),
    }
}
```

Now we can add the bootstrap icons in our app.scss file:

```
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```

At last we want to build:

```
sail npm run build
```

Now you can use bootstrap icons in you're html by:

```
<i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
```

If you are not using sail u can run it without the "sail" part and should use `npm run dev` to rebuild and use the application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install bootstrap icons by running following command: `npm install bootstrap-icons`
2. Check if icons where installed: `npm list bootstrap-icons` you should get a version if not bootstrap-icons are not installed retrying installing by using yarn or command from first step.
3. Add this import statement to your resources/sass/app.scss `@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run dev`
6. `npm run watch`
7. Now you can use icons simply by using tags `<i class="bi bi-0-circle"></i>`  in view.blade.php or by searching icons on [bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)

8. if you get error related to vite.config.js then make sure this add to resolve

9. ````
       alias: {
           vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
           '@': '/node_modules',
       },
   },```
   ````