# How can I use fontawesome icons in a laravel application using vite?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, font-awesome, laravel-blade, vite

I have installed **@fortawesome/fontawesome-free** package using npm. The latest Laravel application uses vite by default. I am unable to solve this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. My **vite.config.js** is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
            'resources/admin/css/app.css',
            'resources/admin/js/app.js',
            'resources/css/glide.css',
            'resources/js/glide.js',
            'resources/js/Sortable.js',
            'resources/js/tinymce.js',
            'resources/sass/app.scss',
            'resources/admin/sass/app.scss',
        ]),
        {
            name: 'blade',
            handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
                if (file.endsWith('.blade.php')) {
                    server.ws.send({
                        type: 'full-reload',
                        path: '*',
                    });
                }
            },
        },
        viteStaticCopy({
            targets: [
                {
                    src: 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
                    dest: '',
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

I imported fontawesome scss files in **app.scss**. My **app.scss** file contains

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

I tried using a third party library **https://github.com/sapphi-red/vite-plugin-static-copy** to copy webfonts of fontawesome package. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Can you please add error to the question

Comment: It's specifically /webfonts that needs to be copied to /webfonts public, I expect the rest of the lib to be included by `@import`

Comment: @parth there is no error. when I run `npm run build`, everything works because I have used **viteStaticCopy** which is a third party plugin. But when I run npm run dev, it cannot find the path at **resources/webfonts/**. I could use the same package in this case too, but I found this way a bit hacky and hoping for a better solution.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes I copied the **webfonts** using a third-party plugin. But I found this method a bit hacky when using **vite**. I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this issue. When using **laravel mix**, it automatically handles the **webfont** directory. We didn't have to do the extra stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139847/14344959

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by first installing sass pre-processor:

```
npm install -D sass
```

after that I imported all fontawesome **scss** files into my **app.js** file:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims.scss';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

in **Laravel 9 OR Above**, by default Laravel use [Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite) to bundle your application's CSS and JavaScript files into production ready assets.

Now if you need to use FontAwesome with Vite in laravel then you can do it as below way.

Step 1:- Run `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` command for install Font Awesome. by running above command fontawesome will be installed in **"node_modules" directory** (full path:- {root_dir}/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free).

Step 2:- Open `{root_dir}/vite.config.js` file and add below path in this file

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
            // add below path of fontawesome
            '~fontawesome': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free'), // <- add this line

        }
    },
});
```

Step 3:- Now open `{root_dir}/resources/sass/app.scss` file & import fontawesome scss as like below

```
// Bootstrap
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// for FontAwesome v6+
$fa-font-path: '~fontawesome/webfonts';
@import '~fontawesome/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~fontawesome/scss/brands';
@import '~fontawesome/scss/solid';
```

Note that, in last step we import the fontawesome files. but that import path may different. here currently I used latest version (6.4) of FontAwesome. [Refer this for more read about "how to use fontAwesome with Sass"](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/scss)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy if you are not adding it via npm. Copy entire fontawesome dir into resources dir `(/resources/fontawesome)`, then declare variable in your scss file like (assuming you are doing it in a file inside /resources/sass:

```
$fa-font-path: '../fontawesome/webfonts';
```

and import fontawesome files:

```
@import '../fontawesome/scss/brands';
@import '../fontawesome/scss/solid';
@import '../fontawesome/scss/light';
@import '../fontawesome/scss/fontawesome';
```

Build script will copy files to your `/public/build/assets` dir and change urls and dev script will load them from your resources dir.

Answer (score 0):

**More simple way !** the js file of the package has everything !

1 Install the package

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

2 Import it in resources/**js/app.js** only what you need to minimize the size.

```
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome';

@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid';
```

3 Enjoy

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-sort"></i>
```

You also need to have sass installed. Nothing to change in vite conf.

My vite conf if you need :

```
import {defineConfig, preprocessCSS} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import * as path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```