# Vite 3.0.9 not compiling scss files with Laravel v9.26.1

Tags: sass, node-modules, vite, laravel-9

basically having a slight compilation issue with Vite.js. The following code is my vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

For some reason the `~` in the app.scss does not work. I think this comes from the sass loader originally but not 100% sure on how to get this to work. My `app.scss` looks like:

```
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// ADMINLTE
@import '~admin-lte/build/scss/adminlte';
```

If I remove the `~` it still compiles but the sub package AdminLTE has many `~` references within the package and the error is:

```
 Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
     ╷
  10 │ @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
     │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is inside the adminlte.scss (inside node_modules).

I have looked at a couple of fixes, but from the docs it says to use `npm add -D sass` which I have installed. Not sure if I need to revert to Laravel Mix as this does it out of the box, or is there a fix I haven't found like importing and using `sass-loader`?

Any support would be very greatful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139847/14344959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
```

use the following

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
```

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if there was a standard way to load packages... 

Seems like each build tool does it differently.

Answer (score -1):

change

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css']);
```

to

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss'])
```