# How to install Bootstrap 5 on Laravel 9 with Vite?

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, sass, vite

I followed the following guide:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/

and I still get all sorts of errors, sometimes file is not found or sometimes I just don't see the bootstrap design.

I installed Bootstrap using npm:

```
npm install bootstrap@5.2.2
```

Then I installed scss using npm:

```
npm i --save-dev sass
```

Then I added the following to `vite.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'nodes_modules/bootstrap'),
    }
}
```

Also added the following to `/resources/app.js`:

```
import '/resources/scss/styles.scss'    
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

I also created a new `scss` folder in `/resources` and placed the following `styles.scss` file inside:

```
// Import all of Bootstrap's CSS
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But when I use `npm run dev` or `build`, the Bootstrap styling don't show up, or I'm getting error about files not existing, for example:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/myapp/nodes_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap
```

Comment: please, add your `vite.config.js` file content to the question.

Comment: refer this for compile sass with vite in laravel https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139847/14344959

Answer (score 8):

**Install Bootstrap 5 in Laravel 9 with Vite**

1. Install Bootstrap 5 and dependencies
   To install Bootstrap from the command terminal execute the following instructions

```
npm i bootstrap sass @popperjs/core --save-dev
```

2. Configure Vite and dependencies
   Rename the file: resources/css/app.css to: resources/css/app.scss
   Open the vite.config.js file found in the root of the project and change the reference resources/css/app.css to resources/css/app.scss

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

In the resources/css/app.scss file import Bootstrap by adding the following line of code

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

In the file resources/js/bootstrap.js add the following lines

```
...
import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core'
window.Popper = Popper
import 'bootstrap'
...
```

3. Change .blade for Hot reloading

In the resources/views/welcome.blade.php file, paste the following code before the closing  tag:

```
...
   @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.scss'])
</head>
<body>
...
```

4. Test
   Run dev server with command:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: what happened my custom css file. how can I import bootstrap with custom style.css file.